# Deploying my first Azure VM for a FileMaker Server

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, azure, filemaker

As the title states, I'm deploying my first Azure VM for a FileMaker Server and I would love some recommended settings to start me out. I know I need to open port 5003 to allow FileMaker clients to access the server but I can't figure out how to do that. I tried to go through the advanced settings in Windows Firewall and add a rule to Incoming Connections but it still says the connection unavailable on that port on my end. I'm using Windows Server 2012 R2 as my instance. It comes preset with a lot of security settings but I don't really know how to work with them. I work primarily on Macs.

Comment: You need to configure your Azure Network Security Group to allow the inbound connections.

Comment: @joeqwerty genius. that did it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to configure your Azure Network Security Group to allow the inbound connections.